# Laravel 5.4 - How to count the absences of the employee from the table

Tags: laravel-5

How can I count the number of absences of the employee? can someone help me with this, please? thank you very much!

For example, i want to count the total absences of the bio_emp = 9.

This is the snippet of the table

[image: table]

Comment: can you be a bit more specific? do you wanna count the total of absence? or per day?

Comment: thank you for your fast response. i want to count the total of absence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about that? considering that the table is called "Attendance"

```
$absences=Attendance::where(['absence', '=', 1],
                            ['bio_emp', '=', 9])
                     ->count();
```

or

```
$absences=Attendance::where('absence', '=', 1)
                     ->where('bio_emp', '=', 9)
                     ->count();
```

.. as mentioned below in the comment ... you can omit the equal sign .. but I prefer to use it :)

Comment: you dont have to declare equal sign it is by default, and yes you can chain like that

Comment: both are acceptable .. I prefer to stick with using the signs... make it more readable/understandable for someone not really familiar with the code

Comment: Thank you very much sir @Mr.P! you gave me a great idea to my code! This is the code:
"$emp->absent = Employee_Bio_Flag::where('absent', '=', 1)
                     ->where('bio_emp', '=', $emp->bio_no)
                     ->count();" 
and it works!